# Let $\Gamma = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in \Bbb Q, y \in \Bbb R \}$. Show that $\Gamma$ is measurable and $m(\Gamma)=0.$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\Gamma = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in \Bbb Q, y \in \Bbb R \}$. Show that $\Gamma$ is measurable and $m(\Gamma)=0.$

It seems that there isn't a clear definition on how to classify set as measurable? I'm trying to work with $\Gamma$ to see if I get something. It seems that $$\Gamma= \{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \in \Bbb Q \} \cup  \{(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \in \Bbb R \}\\ = \Bbb Q \times \Bbb R \cup \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$$

Would it satisfy to show that these two sets $(\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are measurable?

Comment: That union is not correct. Indeed, $$(\Bbb Q \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R) = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of $\Gamma$ is wrong. $\Gamma =\mathbb  Q \times \mathbb R$ which makes this set a Borel set in $\mathbb R^{2}$. Also, its measure is $m(\mathbb Q)m(\mathbb R)=0$ since $0 .\infty$ is interpreted as $ 0$ in the definition of product measure.

Comment: Isn't the comma in $\Gamma = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in \Bbb Q, y \in \Bbb R \}$ read as $x\in \Bbb Q$ or $y \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: No. It is read as $x \in \mathbb Q$ **and** $y \in \mathbb R$. @Danlo